# Restcomm in Amazon ECS

Tags: restcomm, amazon-ecs

I am trying to run Restcomm using the docker image in Amazon ECS but I found some problems.

This is the command I'm running:

> docker run 
>   -e ENVCONFURL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Docker/master/scripts/restcomm_env_basicAmazon.sh"
>
> -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 9990:9990 -p 5060:5060 -p 5061:5061 -p 5062:5062 -p 5063:5063 -p 5060:5060/udp -p 65000-65050:65000-65050/udp
>   restcomm/restcomm:latest

I'm able to access to the administration portal, olympus and RVD but when I call +1234 or receive a call from Nexmo, it fails, here the logs: https://gist.github.com/antonmry/61ec970be3ff9fd923538899768bbc76

I guess the problem is related to run restcomm_env_basicAmazon.sh but not sure about that. How do you run it in Amazon? Some help would be welcomed.

Best regards,

Antón

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see in the logs below that you didn't specify the VoiceRSS key or the free VoiceRSS key that ships by default is all consumed. Please create a new VoiceRSS key, set it in your own configuration file and retry

```
[0m[31m19:36:02,601 ERROR [org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.tts.VoiceRSSSpeechSynthesizer] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-111) There was an exception while trying to synthesize message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.tts.api.SpeechSynthesizerException: ERROR: The API key is not available!
[0m[0m19:36:02,602 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-111)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$y Current State: synthesizing
```

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks for your help. I was using a different with the env variable VOICERSS_KEY. I tried again with a new one but the same behavior happens. Even when I'm not using VoiceRSS (for example in the second log for nexmo fowarding), if I create a simple application returning a Busy here, it works. But if I try to forward the call to another number, it fails. I think it's a problem of communication with the Media Server because of the port mappings. It makes sense?. How are you running the docker images in Amazon?

Comment: @AntónR.Yuste in both logs it shows the same issue of VoiceRSS key as described in my previous comments, if you updated the VoiceRSS Key, please provide new logs so we can check what new errors you got.

Comment: here the log: https://gist.github.com/antonmry/61ec970be3ff9fd923538899768bbc76#file-call-nexmo-play . Also the situation is now a bit better, able to forward the call to a different number, but when I try to play a file (for example https://github.com/RestComm/sip-servlets/blob/master/sip-servlets-examples/media-jsr309-servlet/src/main/sipapp/audio/dtmf_welcome.wav ), the calls starts but not sound is played. Here the new list of ENVs and ports I'm using  as docker parameters: https://gist.github.com/antonmry/f925eda8b8c9a0ef33dc3a8584ab0873

Comment: Solved, we were using the range 65000 to 65050 for the Media Server but only opening from 65000 to 65012 in Amazon, that was the problem! Thanks for your help @jeand

Comment: Great. Thanks @AntónR.Yuste for posting the final solution to the issue !